# return to top of treeview when clicking tree node in the bottom in the GWT app

Tags: gwt, scroll, treeview

I recently start to work on the source codes written in GWT. I do not have any knowledge on GWT at all. There is a tree view, which is working well in IE and FireFox, however it does not work in Chrome. When clicking a certain node, it return to the top of the tree in the Chrome. Actually, that treeview resides in the scroll box, it goes up to top of the scroll box when clicking node in the bottom. What would be the clue of this issue? Any clue I can investigate into would be welcomed :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue you are facing - if you are talking about the Tree from GXT. You can solve it when you override the focus method to do nothing

```
@Override
public void focus() {
    //override to fix focus issue
}
```